# Making $facebook->api to load faster and post to album to upload faster?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code. Everytime i load this page, it takes 3-5 seconds if there is no user_id information. Can i reduce the time to make it load faster?

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id) {
echo "have user";
try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user_id = null;
}
$_SESSION['facebook']= $_SESSION;
$_SESSION['user_profile'] = $user_profile;
} else {
    echo "no user";
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
      'scope'         => 'publish_stream, user_likes'
    )
    );
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl'; </script>";
}
```

I also have the following code to post images to user album. It takes about 4-8 seconds before it echo "success". Any way to make it faster?

```
//Session start
$user_profile = $_SESSION['user_profile'];
$user_id = $user_profile['id'];

// Do the wall post.
$msg_new = "hello";
$link = "XXXXYYYY";
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$imgURL = "user_img/".$user_id.".jpg";
$args = array('message' => $msg_new.$link);
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($imgURL);

$facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
$result = "success";
echo $result;
```

FYI: I'm testing this on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

> FYI: I'm testing this on localhost.

Then the requests are probably delayed by a (comparatively) slow internet connection, by competing with the other requests your machine is handling at the same time (music streaming, p2p, …), etc.

I wouldn’t worry about that, and see how it behaves once you put it up on a “real” web server, which probably has a much better connection that your home machine. If it’s still slow on there, *then* it’d be time for further investigation of the matter.

Comment: Hi CBroe, i already put this on the real webserver. The speed is not much different.

Comment: I realized that the problem doesn't due to the $loginURL, but on $facebook->api to get user data. I used microtime to measure the duration on facebook api. The duration range from 1 sec to 30 sec. Any work around to make it faster? Will FQL make it faster?